# List of strings - partial entry StartsWith using LINQ

Tags: c#

Imagine I have this code

```
public List<string> X
```

and I load the following items:

> launch.txt
>   reset.txt
>   foldername
>   otherfoldername

I know I can find if an item is on that list by calling X.Contains("value")
but what if I pass "foldername/file.txt".

What's the easiest way to check if a string starts with any of the entries on the X list?
Ideally I want to catch all files that are inside "foldername/*.*" and subdirectories too, so I thought to use the StartWith.

Is LINQ the right approach for this?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Also, FYI, the term is "thanks in advance", not "thanks in advanced".

Comment: to put it shortly - yes , it is the right approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Enumerable.Any` extension method, which returns `true` if and only if there is some item in the sequence for which the given predicate returns `true`.

```
string search = "foldername/file.txt";
bool result = X.Any(s => search.StartsWith(s));
```

Of course, `StartsWith` might not actually be appropriate for your scenario.  What if there were only a folder named `foldername2` in `X`?  You wouldn't want `result` to be `true` in that case, I suspect.

---

If you want to get the items in `X` that match the search, you can do the following.

```
string search = "foldername/file.txt";
IEnumerable<string> result = X.Where(s => search.StartsWith(s));
```

If you want to get the first item in `X` that matches the search, you can do the following.

```
string search = "foldername/file.txt";
string result = X.FirstOrDefault(s => search.StartsWith(s));
```

Comment: Yes in fact, I decided to put a "\" at the end of each folder to ensures it picks up the right one. Thanks a lot ..

Comment: @Developer In the example you gave, the search contained a forward slash, not a backslash. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Path` class if you are fiddling around with paths:

```
List<string> X = new List<string>(){
    "launch.txt","reset.txt","foldername","otherfoldername"    
};
string search = "foldername/file.tx";
var searchInfo = new
{
    FileNameWoe = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(search),
    FileName = Path.GetFileName(search),
    Directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(search)
};

IEnumerable<String> matches = X.Select(x => new
{
    str = x,
    FileNameWoe = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x),
    FileName = Path.GetFileName(x),
    Directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(x)
}).Where(xInfo => searchInfo.FileName    == xInfo.FileNameWoe
               || searchInfo.FileNameWoe == xInfo.FileName
               || searchInfo.Directory   == xInfo.Directory
               || searchInfo.Directory   == xInfo.FileNameWoe
               || searchInfo.FileNameWoe == xInfo.Directory)
.Select(xInfo => xInfo.str)
.ToList();
```

Finds: `foldername` because one of the filename's `FileNameWithoutExtension` equals the  directory of the path you're searching.